Open API definition empty with Sprint boot 3 and spring security
I have setup a spring boot project using spring boot version 3.3.5 and added springdoc version 2.6.0, this project also includes spring security and my Security config is as follow:
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .sessionManagement(
            session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .authorizeHttpRequests(
            auth ->
                auth.requestMatchers("/actuator/**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html")
                    .permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/reset-password")
                    .permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/validate-account")
                    .permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/forgot-password")
                    .permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/validate-token")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated());
    http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
  }

The security config class is annotated with both @Configuration, @EnableWebSecurity and @EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
Based on their official doc, including just the springdoc dependency it should expose the open api swagger definition under the path: /v3/api-docs which can be accessed as shown from the image but returns an empty response:

For the record, I'm using the following dependency 'cause I don't need the UI:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
        </dependency>


Do you have any demo app code where we can replicate this behavior?
